# How to deal with prototype pollution attack vulnerability in lodash?

Tags: javascript, npm, prototype-pollution, lodash

[lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) has been reported to be vulnerable to the so called prototype pollution attack in versions up to (excluding) 4.17.5
See https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2018-3721

Now lodash is **the** [most depended upon package](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/depended) in the JavaScript eco system. The impact is that almost every at least mid-scale project has gazillions of different lodash dependencies and sub-dependencies in different versions included (run `npm ls | grep lodash` in a JS project of your choice to see for yourself). Now it will take lots and lots of effort and a lot of time to contribute to all of the open source projects that use lodash in version < 4.17.5.

Please explain, how can this vulnerability be used by attackers and what would be the right way to deal with this issue in a large scale frontend that has **A LOT** of production dependencies using lodash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are several questions cramped into one, so I will try to answer each one individually:

## What is prototype pollution and how can it be used by an attacker?

I don't know how much JavaScript knowledge you have, so I will try to remain as generic as possible. JavaScript uses prototypes extensively to implement object inheritance. Basically, whatever you write into the prototype will be in the object instances. The [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) will explain this far better than I could.

According to the [report on HackerOne](https://hackerone.com/reports/310443), if an attacker is able to insert their own data into lodash, they are able to add their own code to the object. The following PoC demonstrates this:

```
var _= require('lodash');
var malicious_payload = '{"__proto__":{"oops":"It works !"}}';

var a = {};
console.log("Before : " + a.oops);
_.merge({}, JSON.parse(malicious_payload));
console.log("After : " + a.oops);
```

If you run this code, you can see that `a` is modified, even if it is never written to directly.

So how does this affect your application? Well, this depends on your code. There is no "catch-all" answer. In some cases it can be a denial of service, in others a remote code execution.

For instance, one could replace the function `toString()` with a literal string. Attempting to call a string will result in an error, thus leading to a denial of service.

## How can a large-scale application deal with a vulnerable package?

Either update your lodash version as soon as possible or apply a manual backport patch yourself. It might not be easy, but it's absolutely necessary.

If your application *never* processes any user input, then you may delay the update until you can, but it should be pretty high on your priority list.

Comment: Regarding the _“How does this affect your application?”_ part: I know there is no “catch-all” answer, but could you add some examples? Many thanks!

Comment: I added the example linked in the HackerOne report. But this is one of the issues where the effect is truly dependent on the individual codebase.

Comment: @MechMK1 What do you mean by manual backport patch

Comment: @PragamShrivastava Backporting means keeping a lower version number for compatibility reason, but "porting" a security patch "back" to the lower version number. That means even though the application uses a vulnerable version, the vulnerability itself is patched. Manual backporting means one would have to do this process themselves if no official backport is available.

Comment: Which upgraded version of lodash solves this vulnerability ?

Comment: @KartikBhatia 4.17.21 is the latest version and the only one without known vulnerabilities.